# Loop for dentro de loop for

Tags: c, array, loop, for, complexidade-de-algoritmo

```
for(pass = 0; pass < size - 1; pass++){
    for(j = 0; j < size - 1; j++){

        if(array[j] > array[j + 1]){
            swap( &array[j], &array[j + 1]);
         }
     }
 }
```

Coloquei só um pedaço do código onde eu tenho dúvida, mas a intenção é colocar em ordem crescente os números de um *array* de tamanho 10. A parte que eu não entendo é a utilidade do segundo *loop* `for`, dentro do *loop* for externo. dada a *array*.

```
a = { 2, 6, 4, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37}
```

Apenas um *loop* seria o suficiente para colocar em ordem crescente, mas por que é necessário um outro *loop*?

o exercício tem como comentário nesse *loops* o seguinte:

```
1° loop = loop to control passes
2° loop = loop to control comparisons during each pass.
```

Comment: Um loop não é suficiente. Não sei se está afirmando ou perguntando, pois não tem interrogação.

Comment: o loop interno vai de 0 a 9 certo, pra depois sair e incrementar + 1 no loop externo que vai de 0 a 9 tbm, se apenas o loop interno que vai fazer 9 tentativas não for suficiente, é necessario exatamente 9 + 9 = 18 tentativas para por em ordem crescente?

Comment: Na verdade são 81 iterações com os loops aninhados.

Comment: Não necessariamente, se você verificar se já está ordenado, uma simples flag bool da conta disso. O pior caso(ordem inversa) levará a 81 interação, pois para mim aparenta ser um Bubble Sort.

Comment: Sim, no pior caso. E no caso do código da pergunta, que não tem flag nem break. Independente de executar ou não o swap, são 81 iterações. O que é irrelevante em termos de performance considerando a array de entrada da pergunta, que é pequena. Espero não estar confundindo o Vitor, estou só tentando esclarecer :)

Comment: Desculpa, 81 iterações, mas ( colocando no papel) por que eu vejo em apenas no loop interno os termos ficando em ordem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa é mais uma questão de lógica e matemática.

Até tem maneiras diferentes de fazer isso, mas neste exemplo precisa de dois laços porque o interno apenas compara um par por vez e inverte se o segundo for o menor, mas isso não garante trocas além do par. O laço externo vai mandar fazer outras vezes para garantir que analise de novo e vá trazendo os menores cada vez mais para o início>

Vamos fazer um teste de mesa:

```
2, 6, 4, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37

Compara 2 e 6 e não faz nada
Compara 6 e 4 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37
Compara 6 e 8 e não faz nada
Compara 8 e 10 e não faz nada
Compara 10 e 12 e não faz nada
Compara 12 e 89 e não faz nada
Compara 89 e 68 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 68, 89, 45, 37
Compara 89 e 45 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 68, 45, 89, 37
Compara 89 e 37 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 68, 45, 37, 89
```

Está ordenado? Não. Melhorou, mas ainda precisa ordenar mais:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 68, 45, 37, 89

Compara 2 e 4 e não faz nada
Compara 4 e 6 e não faz nada
Compara 6 e 8 e não faz nada
Compara 8 e 10 e não faz nada
Compara 10 e 12 e não faz nada
Compara 12 e 68 e não faz nada
Compara 68 e 45 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 45, 68, 37, 89
Compara 68 e 37 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 45, 37, 68, 89
Compara 89 e 37 e inverte 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 68, 45, 37, 89
```

Está ordenado? Não. Melhorou, mas ainda precisa ordenar mais e assim terá que fazer outras vezes até ter tudo ordenado.

Não é o mais eficiente, mas esse código trabalha assim. Como já disseram em comentários é possível marcar quando já está ordenada e não fazer todos passos. Na verdade é possível não fazer as trocas onde já está ok. Mas aí é outro algoritmo bem diferente.

Vamos ver como fica:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *e1, int *e2) {
    int tmp = *e1;
    *e1 = *e2;
    *e2 = tmp;
}

void imprime(int array[], int size) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) printf("%d, ",array[j]);
     printf("\n");
}
    
int main(void) {
    int array[10] = { 2, 6, 4, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37 };
    int size = 10;
    for (int pass = 0; pass < size - 1; pass++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) swap(&array[j], &array[j + 1]);
            imprime(array, size);
         }
         printf("--- Nova iteração ---\n");
     }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/MeMqGR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ffqcbuhm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/NaiveSort.c).